# TexStudio: Cursor in editor moves to end of word

Tags: texstudio, macos

whenever i try to type in any character, the cursor in texstudio jumps to the end of the current word and adds the character there. I'm unable to correct any typo inside of words and/or commands.

[image: Whenever i try to enter a letter in the middle of a word, the cursor jumps to its end and adds it there]

I've already [asked the developers](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/423) a while ago, but they couldn't help. Maybe someone here can.

What I've tried so far:
- Update/Downgrade texstudio (right now i'm on v 2.12.22)
- Delete .config/texstudio/texstudio.ini

I'm running macOS 10.13.6.

Thanks

Comment: could it be something related to the auto-completion? There are different aspects of autocompletion that can be toggled on and off, but I think unchecking Options -> Completion -> "Automatically start completer when typing LaTeX-Commands".

Comment: Thank You for that hint. Unfortunately, unchecking that option (or any other option in that collumn) doens't help.